# Haskell: Variable Type confusion between Double and Int

Tags: haskell, types

As an uni assignment, I was supposed to write a function with the type declaration:

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
```

and this was my first attempt:

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
pi_approx x = let total = sum [1 / (y^2) | y <- [1..x]]
    in sqrt (6 * total)
```

which threw the below error:

```
pi_approx.hs:4:8: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'  
    * In the expression: sqrt (6 * total)
      In the expression:
        let total = sum [1 / (y ^ 2) | y <- ...] in sqrt (6 * total)
      In an equation for `pi_approx':
          pi_approx x = let total = sum ... in sqrt (6 * total)
  |
4 |     in sqrt (6 * total)
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I went step by step trying to understand why the interpreter treats it as an Int:

```
level1 :: Fractional a => a -> a
level1 x = 1 / (x^2)
```

So far so good.

```
level2 :: (Enum a, Fractional a) => a -> [a]
level2 x = [level1 y | y <- [1..x]]
```

Also as expected.

```
level3 :: (Enum a, Fractional a) => a -> a
level3 x = sum (level2 x)
```

No Int to be seen...

```
level4 :: (Enum a, Fractional a) => a -> a
level4 x = 6 * (level3 x)
```

and finally

```
level5 :: (Floating a, Enum a) => a -> a
level5 x = sqrt (level4 x)
```

And having gone down this rabbit hole I'm no closer to my answer. I got it running with `fromIntegral`

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
pi_approx x = let total = sum [(fromIntegral 1) / ((fromIntegral y)^ (fromIntegral 2)) | y <- [1..x]]
    in sqrt (6*total)
```

but it got me nowhere nearer to understanding what caused the error in the first version. Could someone explain what I'm missing? Why was `sqrt (6*total)` treated as an `Int`?

Comment: I really like the plan you cooked up for experimenting. An observation: when doing your tests, you switched all the type signatures to be polymorphic instead of concrete. If you had started with the concrete type `level1 :: Int -> Double` it would have stopped you in your tracks right there (or, if you had started with the concrete type `level1 :: Double -> Double` then you would have soon discovered that your `level5` had no `Int` anywhere in its type signature).

Comment: Numerical constants such as 1, 2, 6, may have any numeric type. You can check this in the_ghci_ interpreter, entering “:type 6”. So you only need the `(fromIntegral y)` converter. The `Int` type constraint on the argument x propagates unmitigated to y. Hence the type conflict in your initial code at the level of the “/” operator. Unlike in C C++ Fortran, there is no automatic numeric type promotion. You have to allow it explicitely for it to happen.

Comment: @DanielWagner I suspect the definitions were typed in without signatures, and the polymorphic types were copied from GHCi's `:t` command, as deduced by it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because of the way typeclasses are type checked, the type error you were shown is not the most helpful one.

```
[ 1 / (y^2) | y <- [1..x] ]
```

So it is probably no surprise that, because `x` is an `Int`, `[1..x]` is a list of `Int`s and so `y` is an `Int`.  Nor is it surprising that `y^2` is an `Int`.  Where GHC loses us is when it decides that therefore `1 / (y^2)` is an `Int`.

The reason is this: the type of the divide operator is

```
(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
```

That is, it takes the same type on both sides, and also returns it. So as soon as the type of `y^2` is known to be `Int`, we infer that `1` and the entire expression are `Int` also.  *Only later*, during the constraint checking phase, GHC will make sure that `Int` is `Fractional`, which of course it is not.  For example:

```
recp :: Int -> Int
recp x = 1 / x
```

Will give you a better error

```
• No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
• In the expression: 1 / x
  In an equation for ‘recp’: recp x = 1 / x
```

But it didn't get that far when checking your function, because there was a type unification failure first.

Sometimes if you can't figure out an error it is helpful to remove the signature and see what type is inferred (more often, it's helpful to add more type signatures, but not always)

```
ghci> :t pi_approx
pi_approx :: (Floating a, Enum a) => a -> a
```

Without the signature, the function actually type-checks.  It works, too:

```
ghci> pi_approx 100
3.1320765318091053
```

Here `100` is defaulted to be a `Double` to satisfy the `Fractional` constraint, and the whole definition goes through with everything as `Double`s.

It's just that it doesn't accept `Int`s:

```
ghci> pi_approx (100 :: Int)

<interactive>:1:1: error:
• No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘pi_approx’
• In the expression: pi_approx (1 :: Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the level functions you've defined have the type `a -> a` (or `a -> [a]`) with some constraints on `a` attached to them. So in all cases the type that comes out will be the type that went in (or a list thereof).

So when calling each of your `level` functions there are two possible outcomes: either the call is ill-typed because the type of the argument does not meet the constraints or you'll get back a value of the same time (or a list thereof). Either way it's impossible that you'd put in an `Int` and get back a `Float`.

So `sqrt (6*total)` was treated as an `Int` because, as we've just discussed, the type that comes out will be the same type that goes in and the type that came in was `Int`. Now the type that came in didn't actually meet the constraints, so you might expect an error about that. And without the type signature, you'd get exactly that error (once the function is called with an argument of type `Int`). But with the type signature, the error about the return type not matching is detected before the constraints are checked, so that's why you get that error.

Answer (score 2):

**Everyone explained why it is wrong but no-one showed you how to fix it.**

Here is how you fix your code so that it works

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
pi_approx x = let total = sum [1 /(fromIntegral (y^2)) | y <- [1..x]]
    in sqrt (6 * total)
```

once you add in `fromIntegral` the type checker will be satisfied. As was explained by the other users the type of the function `/` wasn't being satisfied.

Comment: The OP showed a fix at the end of the question. Your answer does not address the question.

Comment: the type of `(/)` was satisfied perfectly well as the other *answers* are saying. the comment you refer to is erroneous in this regard.

Comment: @WillNess Actually it seems that you may be mistaken. Please recall that the OP forced the type `pi_approx :: Int -> Double`. Let's see what happens  if I force an `Int` into the function `/`. In my version of GHCI the following occurs `Prelude> x = 5 :: Int`
`Prelude> 1/x`

`<interactive>:4:1: error:`
    `• No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’`
    `• In the expression: 1 / x`
      `In an equation for ‘it’: it = 1 / x` So it seems that GHCI and I would beg to differ. Thank you for taking the time to read my comments this whole test was very instructional for me.

Comment: @CarstenS Do you think that `(fromIntegral 1) / ((fromIntegral y)^ (fromIntegral 2))` is a better solution than `1 /(fromIntegral (y^2))`? This at face value seems to be an aesthetic question but upon deeper inspection, you will find that `1 /(fromIntegral (y^2))` gets to the heart of the matter; i.e. since the following `pi_approx :: Int -> Double` was forced the problem lies in the `y` and therefore `(fromIntegral 1) / ((fromIntegral y)^ (fromIntegral 2))` is a "plug and play engineer ad hoc solution" whereas my solution "addresses the question" quite directly and contrarily to your beliefs.

Comment: Instance checking comes later, after the type is deduced. if some imported module were defining the missing `Fractional Int` instance, the type would not be rejected. compare `head 1`'s error message with that of `head (1::Int)`. it is the latter that talks about type mismatch, i.e. there's no possible type for that expression. but the first one *could* be valid, if only there were `instance Num [a]` in scope.

Comment: @WillNess **`Int` is not part of the type class `Fractional`.** You *could* define `Int` as an instance of `Fractional` (sure why not), but that doesn't change the fact that: **Since `Int` is not (currently) an instance of the typeclass `Fractional` it is an *error (a type error to be exact)* to pass an `Int` into a function of type `Fractional`.** End of story. You can clearly see the error message. At this point, you are performing insane acts of (ad hoc) acrobatics in order to save face. Both the (GHC) compiler and the standard definition of the type class `Fractional` disagree with you.

Comment: @PedroJuanSoto that's nothing personal, you know. :) that's just how I understand this thing. I find it useful to separate the two cases: where an expression is entirely without type, or just has some instance missing. Of course we know that there can't be any sensible implementation of Fractional for Int here, but in some other case it might, for some other constraint. So there are two phases in type checking: type inference, and constraints resolving, and I find it useful to acknowledge this. there are cases where this phase separation prevents GHC inferring a correct type, so it's relevant.

Comment: @WillNess My bad for getting all personal lol XD, I can get a bit carried away. I understand the point you are trying to make; you could make it right by adding more code so that in theory it could be correct syntax. I get it (*but without the extra code it is wrong* ;) lol). I was just upset because I thought you were implying that I didn't know the difference between a type and a type class (which is a core/foundational feature of Haskell) and it felt like a personal attack, mea culpa. Take care :)